# MPMoviePlayerViewController becomes black when enters background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have problem with MPMoviePlayerViewController , when app enters background and then I launch it again or go another viewControllers  the movie became black ! I have movie which plays in the background of my menus , here is my code :

**EIDTED CODE :**

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad {
        [self moviePlayer2];
    } 

   - (void) moviePlayer2 {



    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cloud" ofType:@"mp4"];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    player.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;    
    player.moviePlayer.repeatMode = YES;
    player.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    player.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackStateChange:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:[player moviePlayer]];

     [[player moviePlayer] play];

    [self.view addSubview:player.view]; 

}


-(void) moviePlayBackStateChange: (NSNotification *) note {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:[player moviePlayer]];

    [[player moviePlayer] play];

    //[player release];
    NSLog(@"FINISHED");
}
```

thank you .

Comment: does `movieFinishedPlaying` get called when your app goes into the background?  If you don't know, set a breakpoint (or use a NSLog to the console) and find out.

Comment: when I switch between the viewControllers yes . compiler show me the NSLog message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may need to add codes below:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackStateChange:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:[player moviePlayer]];
```

and handle the movie state in the moviePlayBackStateChange method.
The movie will be paused when the movie is playing and the app enters in background, so you need to make the movie resume like below when the app come back from background. If not,the movie will keep the pause state. That's why your app becomes black.

```
[[player moviePlayer] play];
```

then the movie will continue to play.
adding two methods which you should invote when the app comes into background and backs from background:

```
-(void) pauseMovieInBackGround
{
   [player moviePlayer] pause];
   [player.view removeFromSuperview];
}
-(void) resumeMovieInFrontGround
{
   [self.view addSubview:player.view];
   [[player moviePlayer] play];
}
```

Hope this can help you guy.

Comment: thank you where should I put this code ? `[[player moviePlayer] play];` on the would you please see my edited code ... because I have same problem ... after switching views my movie became black !

Comment: the views change with presentmodalview controller and then dissmiss from other views

Comment: would you please re consider my codes ? I really need this answer

Comment: @Mc.Lover you can add [[player moviePlayer] playbackState]; in moviePlayBackStateChange method to monitor the state of movieplayer. All state are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @Mc.Lover what's more, I think you should pause the movie when your app come into the background and remove the view of movie from superview, then add the view of movie and make it play when your app is back from background.

Comment: the problem solved thank you with NSTimer for switching views

Comment: Is there are purpose of removing movieplayer from view and readding it

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[player moviePlayer]];
[player release];
```

To this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[player moviePlayer]];
[movieController.view removeFromSuperview];
[player release];
```

See if that works :D

Comment: Are you replacing the removed view with any other view? If not, that would explain it. Make sure you use "[viewController addSubview:newView];" but replace viewController and newView with your own views