# MPMoviePlayerViewController exits after background

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

When my app goes to background and back, modal view closes. Why is this happend? I tried with pause on and off. I have ARC enabled, if it is a useful info.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController * player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:targetURL];
[player.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
```

Comment: Here is solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344877/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-becomes-black-when-enters-background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this (as I did before I found my own solution), I was able to prevent `MPMoviePlayerViewController` from exiting when the app backgrounds by subclassing it and removing it as an observer of `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`:

```
- (id)initWithContentURL:(NSURL *)contentURL {

    self = [super initWithContentURL:contentURL];

    if (self){

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil]; 

    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to subclass `MPMoviePlayerViewController` - just do following after creating `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instance.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.moviePlayerViewController name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is full code that can help you

```
// Call this to start initialization and play movie
-(void)prepareMoviePlayer:(NSURL *)moviePath
{
    moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:moviePath];

    if ([[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)])
    {
        [[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
        [[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] setFullscreen:YES];
        [[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                              selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:)
                                              name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                              object:nil];
    }
}

- (void) addPlayer
{
    [[[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] view] setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [[self view] addSubview:[[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] view]];
}

static NSTimeInterval t;
// Call this on applicationWillResignActive
-(void) pauseMovieInBackGround
{
    [[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] pause];
    t = [[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] currentPlaybackTime];
    [moviePlayerViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
}

// Call this on applicationWillEnterForeground
-(void) resumeMovieInFrontGround
{
    [self addPlayer];

    [[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] stop];
    [[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] setInitialPlaybackTime:t];
    [[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] play];
}

-(void)moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if([[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown)
    {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                              name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                              object:nil];

        [self addPlayer];
        [[moviePlayerViewController moviePlayer] play];
    }
}

-(void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am coming across this issue. 
I've tried ChrisH's answer, but it didn't work for me until I put removeObserver into viewDidLoad() instead of init().

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

}
```

Then it works. Enjoy it.